# Opening a Pdf file?

Tags: android

I want to open pdf in Android
I am currently using code

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path.get((int) v.getTag()));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But the file is not opening currently.

Regards

Comment: Your code will not open a file but let the user choose a pdf reader if more than one reader is installed. Further you should tell value of file.getAbsoluteParh(). `path.get((int) v.getTag())` That is not very informative!

Comment: @greenapps, what exactly is the error in the code.

Comment: You have not reacted to my comment. Nor did you supply the requested info. Any reason not to do so?

Comment: @greenapps. do u have skype or can u create a room here where we can interact ?

Comment: The room is here:. Just react here and give the requested info. Why do you want to be treated differently?

Comment: ok. should i post my all code